# Use Form Controls Into WCF Service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, controls

I Wrote a program that has two Console application(assusme A & B) and a WCF Service Library.
I connected A and B together so message can be transfer from A to B or B to A(WCF Duplex).
To Do this i added the reference of WCF Service Library to both A & B project.
Now I Want To Change these Console Applications To WinForm application but i cannot do that
because in console application we have console.writeline() that it Can be use in WCF Service Library But In WinForm,MessageBox Cannot be use in WCF Service.

Also I Cannot Add Reference Of A & B to Wcf Service Because it makes Circular Dependency Error

**EDITED :**

This Is The Project With Console Applications :

In Project A Program.cs file :

```
   internal static void StartService()
  {
     myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF.MessageService));

     myServiceHost.Open();
  }

  internal static void StopService()
  {
     if (myServiceHost.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        myServiceHost.Close();
  }

  static void Main()
  {
     StartService();
     Console.WriteLine("Service running; press return to exit");
     Console.ReadLine();
     StopService();
     Console.WriteLine("stopped");
  }
```

In Project B Program.cs file:

```
   class ClientCallback : IMyMessageCallback
{
  public void OnCallback(string message)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("message from the server: {0}", message);
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Client - wait for service");
     Console.ReadLine();

     WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
     EndpointAddress address =
           newEndpointAddress("http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageService/Service1/");

     ClientCallback clientCallback = new ClientCallback();
      InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(clientCallback);

     DuplexChannelFactory<IMyMessage> factory =
        new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyMessage>(context, binding, address);

     IMyMessage messageChannel = factory.CreateChannel();

     messageChannel.MessageToServer("From the client");

     Console.WriteLine("Client - press return to exit");
     Console.ReadLine();

  }
```

}

In IMYMessage.cs File (WCF Service Library):

```
   public interface IMyMessageCallback
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void OnCallback(string message);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyMessageCallback))]
public interface IMyMessage
{
  [OperationContract]
  void MessageToServer(string message);
}
```

In MessageService.cs File(WCF Service Library) :

```
 public class MessageService : IMyMessage
{
  public void MessageToServer(string message)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("message from the client: {0}", message);
     IMyMessageCallback callback =
           OperationContext.Current.
                 GetCallbackChannel<IMyMessageCallback>();

     callback.OnCallback("message from the server");

     new Thread(ThreadCallback).Start(callback);
   }

   private void ThreadCallback(object callback)
   {
     IMyMessageCallback messageCallback = callback as IMyMessageCallback;
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        messageCallback.OnCallback("message " + i.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using currently and how you are trying to communicate between the two forms.. WE ARE NOT MIND READERS...!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised you were able to get it working with the Console applications, I expected you to get a Circular Dependency there too.

I think you should restructure your solution so **A & B don't reference each other**.  You are using WCF for communication so they don't need to be referenced in any way.

Also, the WCF library should not do any UI type behaviour such as console write lines or message box stuff, just return a string or object and have you UI application such as your console app or Forms App handle the user interaction/display

```
        -----------            -----------
        |         |            |         |
        |    A    |            |    B    |
        |(Console)|            | (FORMS) |
        |         |            |         |
        -----------   DUPLEX   -----------
        |  Comms  |<==========>|  Comms  |
        |  (WCF)  |            |  (WCF)  |
        -----------            -----------
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,i edited my question and pasted my codes,i am newbie to WCF and I saw something like this example into Wrox Book and i implemented this like that!

Comment: A & B do not reference to each other!I add reference of WCF Service In A & B